# Batch Processing Pan sharpening in Erdas Imagine 2015

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to find a way to batch process HPF Resolution Merge in Erdas Imagine 2015. I cannot find the option for running it in batch. Is there a way with python in Spatial modeler? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:
 modeler -nq mergeall.pmdl -meter -state "$PAN_FILE" "$MS_FILE_DIR/$MS_FILE_VSK" "$OUT_FILE" Unsigned_16_bit ignore 'Nearest Neighbour' 0 "None" 1,2,3,4